# Undefined function or method join

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

While compiling this matlab code, I get the error `Undefined function or method 'join' for input arguments of type 'single'`

*Why is it so?*

```
imshow(newimage);
hh=im2single(H_Channel);
ss=im2single(S_Channel);
vv=im2single(V_Channel);

hsv=join(hh,ss,vv);
outputnew=hsv2rgb(hsv);
figure,
imshow(outputnew);
```

Comment: I have the image processing toolbox (matlab R2014b), but it does not contain any function called `join`. So the problem is probably that the function does not exist, or at least, not in this toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

On R2015a `join` is a built-in [function](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/join.html) used to merge two tables. In addition it is not overloaded for input of type `single` which might explain the error message.

It looks like what you are trying to do is catenate arrays. You can use `cat` for this:

```
  dim = 3;
  hsv = cat(dim,hh,ss,vv);
```